# how to use supabase without its authentication ? (authentication outside )

Tags: authentication, supabase, refresh-token

i want to do authentication and user management in an express server connected to a mongodb,

but once the user is authenticated, i want to be able to access the supabase apis, with access to the RLS , so that i don't have to create middleware's for each api ,

i was able to do a part of the above , i was able to create my own JWT access token , with my jwtkey (from express and mongodb)

now with this i was able to authenticate someone that was never added to the supabase user management.

```
## this is the payload that is supplied by the supabase login 
{
  "aud": "authenticated",
  "exp": 1695822576,
  "iat": 1695818976,
  "sub": "e17d96a9-97b6-4afa-b934-a8420d161255",
  "email": "gokul@email.com",
  "phone": "",
  "app_metadata": {
    "provider": "email",
    "providers": [
      "email"
    ]
  },
  "user_metadata": {},
  "role": "authenticated",
  "aal": "aal1",
  "amr": [
    {
      "method": "password",
      "timestamp": 1695818976
    }
  ],
  "session_id": "239876ab-9b89-4965-9821-06cec2ff6165"
}
```

```
###this is the payload i am supplying from express which is working and authenticating the user , and able to pass the authenticated condition in RLS
{
  "aud": "authenticated",
  "exp": 1695822576,
  "iat": 1695818976,
  "sub": "e17d96a9-97b6-4afa-b934-a8420d161255",
  "email": "gokul@email.com",
  "phone": "",
  "app_metadata": {
    "provider": "email",
    "providers": [
      "email"
    ]
  },
  "user_metadata": {},
  "role": "authenticated"
}
```

my current understanding is that i can get RLS to work by adding fields inside app_metadata, or user_metadata , which of these should work ???

the other question is that

this methid works perfectly for http apis , was also able to get this to work for the supabase ORM by manually adding the token to the client
supabaseServerClient.functions.setAuth(token)
supabaseServerClient.realtime.setAuth(token)
but i was unable to handle refresh tokens for the supbase ORM

how do i handle refresh tokens if i manually create signed JWTs myself outside supabase

basically user management will be completely outside supabase

Comment: found some resource about the problem:  https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/pull/340, will add the solution too once i find it

Comment: came across a service called zitadel , looking through setting it up to solve my probem! stopped trying to solve through the jwt approach

Comment: It's the same approach as using Auth0 for example (see step 7 & 8): https://supabase.com/partners/integrations/auth0